# Send help in the form of someone who knows python well

Tags: numpy, package, python-imaging-library, python-3.7

I am currently well versed in java, but I am trying to get into python. I know the basics, but am struggling with package use and implementation into source code.
I have successfully installed both numpy and Pillow (or PIL):
[Click here for cmd telling me both packages have been installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1dPt.png)

When I typed `import numpy` into cmd running python, it worked no problem, but now I've tried to open IDLE and import it there, and written source code trying to import it and utalise parts of the numpy lib but it always gives me a ModuleNotFoundError
[python idle shell import vs. cmd import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X15qc.png)
My folder layout is a little wacky:

```
C:
..Users
....B
......ForImagingProject
........PYTHON
..........(python standard subfolders)
..........Lib
............site-packages
..............numpy and PIL and pip here
```

Any and all help would be appreciated
Thanks ~ B
EDIT: I messed up and my IDLE shortcut was running `idle.pyw` instead of `idle.bat`. Everything working smoothly now.

Comment: Make sure you are running the same python binary

Comment: @wm3ndez both are 32 bit if that's what you mean

Comment: What I mean is that have to make sure that you are running the python executable from the same path. Did you create a virtualenv?

Comment: I messed up and my shortcut was mapped to idle.pyw, not idle.bat. Thanks for your help nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

Check your IDLE's python executable. Is it the same one as in your cmd prompt?

The easiest way to check is to run this:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Look for something like
`'PATH_TO_PYTHON/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7'`
or
`'PATH_TO_PYTHON/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7'`

Make sure this is the same in both the IDLE and in cmd.

Comment: thanks @Sean Christians it turns out the paths are not the same, although some are similar, there are differences. Do you happen to know how I would change the IDLE path? EDIT: I was running the shell off of the idle.pyw script, when i shouldve been running it off of the .bat file. Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 1):

The reason the shell I was working in was unable to recognize the module was because my IDLE shortcut was mapped to `idle.pyw` instead of `idle.bat`. Everything running smoothly now